# Reuse Closure Compiler compilation data

Tags: google-closure-compiler

If I have several applications to separately compile, but they will all individually have the same library compiled into them, does Closure Compiler give you a set of compilation data such that you can compile the library separately from the individual applications and then include that data when compiling the applications so that the library part doesn't need to be recompiled every time?

If so, how does that work?

Comment: No. We really should because it would allow us to do very fast incremental compilation of large programs, but currently we don't have a way to do this.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: Thanks for the info.